# Is it possible to return a different type after reading a configuration section as a .NET ConfigurationCollection?

Tags: c#, .net, collections, configuration, app-config

I am reading a simple collection from app.config:

```
<MongoInstances>
      <MongoInstance serverAddress="server1" />
      <MongoInstance serverAddress="server2" />
</MongoInstances>
```

Into the following field

```
[ConfigurationProperty("MongoInstances")]
[ConfigurationCollection(typeof(MongoInstancesCollection), AddItemName = "MongoInstance")]
    public MongoInstancesCollection ServerUrls
{ ...
}
```

which works as expected, returning the app.config info in a MongoInstancesCollection object.

I would like this field to be a different type and convert the collection object to an IEnumerable as follows:

```
    [ConfigurationProperty("MongoInstances")]
    [ConfigurationCollection(typeof(MongoInstancesCollection), AddItemName = "MongoInstance")]
    public IEnumerable<MongoServerAddress> ServerUrls
    {
        get
        {
            IList<MongoServerAddress> result = new List<MongoServerAddress>();
            var collection = (MongoInstancesCollection)this["MongoInstances"];
            foreach (MongoInstance instance in collection)
            {
                result.Add(new MongoServerAddress(instance.Address));
            }

            return result;
        }
    }
```

But I am getting the following exception:

```
System.Configuration.ConfigurationErrorsException : Property 'MongoInstances' is not a ConfigurationElement.
```

Googled it and found out that if I set the property manually and remove the ConfigurationProperty attribute from the field definition, it goes away:

```
Properties.Add(new ConfigurationProperty("MongoInstances", typeof(MongoInstancesCollection), new MongoInstancesCollection()));
```

But now I am getting a new exception that I cannot figure out how to remediate:

```
System.Configuration.ConfigurationErrorsException : Unrecognized element 'MongoInstance'
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Try something like http://blog.davidtruxall.com/2010/06/02/using-linq-against-a-custom-configurationelementcollection/ and have MangoInstancesCollection inherit from ConfigurationElementCollection and IEnumerable.

Comment: My collection is already implementing IEnumerable<MongoInstance>. Also, in the blog post you've referenced the author still has the ConfigurationElementCollection as the return type for his collection, which is what I am trying to avoid.